# Java: Guessing Game error count

Tags: java, count

Hey guys (I'm New to java B.T.W.)

I am developing a small guessing game using Java and I've been stuck in some problem.
I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me to overcome this problem.

The game is something like this:

- list of guess words are stored in database
- One of the random word is chosen and
- shown to users in disguised form
- The users have to guess the word using letters
- They've 5 letters to guess until the game is
  over

Now my problem is I've been stuck with the error count...

My code is something like this:

```
 //word is the word that user must guess
 // asciiToChar is letter that users've guessed
 // J is just a variable used for count

 for (j=0; j < word.length(); j++)
       {    if (word.charAt(j) != asciiToChar)
            {
             error++;
            }
       }
 System.out.println("Number of Errors: "+" "+ error);
```

Everytime the users perform a wrong guess the error count is supposed to be increased but it's showing some random numbers like 8,14 or something. I need to figure it out on how to increase the count by only one until 5 guesses

And whenever I use `word.charAt(j) != asciiToChar` instead of  `==` It's giving me a right count for correct guesses.

I can't  figure it out :(

Any help would be apprecited

Comment: is this a hangman game?

Comment: So hangman, pretty much?

Comment: Yes pretty much like hangman.
Only the game lacks gui and bodies part...

Comment: @MightyPork
Thanks  a lot
working like a charm :)

Comment: np, glad to help. accept the answer when it becomes possible, please.

Comment: I will,
It wont allow me to accept the answer within 5 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop logic is wrong, it adds error for every single character that doesnt equal the user guess.

Try to do it like this (if I got it right):

```
boolean found = false;
for (j=0; j < word.length(); j++)
{    
    if (word.charAt(j) == asciiToChar)
    {
        found = true;
        break; // no need to search further
    }
}
if(!found) error++; // if the letter isn't used, add 1 error
```

---

As rightfully pointed out by Ingo Bürk in the comments, there's a pre-baked solution for this:

```
if(!word.contains(asciiToChar)) { error++; }
```

Comment: You could also add `break;` after `found = true;` to reduce unnecessary looping.

Comment: Why even loop yourself? `java.lang.String` has a `contains` method, so all you need is `if(!word.contains(asciiToChar)) { error++; }`.

Comment: Oh does it? Thanks for enriching my knowledge. Anyway, I think it's better if he first learns how to do loops and ifs. Lazy can be later.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop goes through all the characters in `word` and for **each** character that doesn't match the one given by the user, it increases errors by one. So if the word is "cat" and the user guesses 'a', you'll get two errors, one for 'c' and one for 't'.